# Individual information in the DTO for the logged-in user

Tags: java, spring, oop

My controller returns the DTO of the `Movie` object

```
public class Movie {
    private final String title;
    private final MovieType type;
    private final List<LanguageType> languages;
    private final List<CountryType> countries;
    ...
}
```

This is the standard movie object I'm returning after calling `/ movies / {id}`. However, I would like to return the rating of the logged in user along with this video. As is the case with, for example, other services like IMDB. When you enter the movie site, this is only a general rating, but if you log in to your account and rate the video, your rating will be given on the video page. So I thought to add to the DTO `Movie` object the box `yourRating` where your rating will be given if you are logged in and rated the video. It would look like this way

```
public class Movie {
    private final String title;
    private final MovieType type;
    private final List<LanguageType> languages;
    private final List<CountryType> countries;
    private final Float yourRating; \\ Twoja ocena
    ...
}
```

I created a thread about it on SO and the user there suggested to create a new `UserMovie` object inheriting from Movie and having only one additional field of yourRating.

I wanted to ask you if this is how it should look like, that the offline `user / movies / {id}` returns DTO Movie, and the currently logged DTO UserMovie object (inherits all `Movie` fields + `yourRating` field). Is it necessary to separate in such a way individual data for the logged in user.